# PHP Lumen Call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm receiving this error when trying to use an Eloquent Model in Lumen.

> Call to a member function connection() on null

Controller func:

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $employees = Employee::orderBy('first_name', 'asc')->get();
dd($employees);

        $response['precontent'] = view('admin::employee.search')->render();

        $response['content'] = view('admin::employee.index')
            ->with(['employees' => $employees])
            ->render();

        $response['title'] = 'Employees';

        return $response; 

    }
```

Model:

```
    <?php
    namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model 
{

    protected $table = 'system_core.employees';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'position',
        'primary_address',
        'secondary_address',
        'phone_1',
        'phone_2',
        'birth_date',
        'start_date',
        'end_date'
    ];

}
```

I'm pretty experienced with Laravel, but just started my first Lumen project for mere API use and I'm not sure why this error is being thrown. Perhaps it's just my connection settings? Would all queries have to be run the following way?:

```
$results = app('db')->select("SELECT * FROM users");
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 147):

You should uncomment the Eloquent `$app->withEloquent()` call in `bootstrap/app.php`.

https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#basic-usage

**Update:**

Latest version of the docs https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/database, check section **Eloquent ORM**

Comment: You also have to uncomment the previous line (`$app->withFacades();`, as Eloquent does use Facades).

Answer (score 19):

You have to:

1. Create the database manually via e.g. PHPMyAdmin;
2. [Configure](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#configuration) the database connection it in the `.env` file (i.e. set `DB_CONNECTION`, `DB_DATABASE`, `DB_USERNAME`, `DB_PASSWORD`);
3. As per above answers [uncomment](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#basic-usage) `$app->withFacades();`, `$app->withEloquent();` lines in `bootstrap/app.php`;
4. If you use your Eloquent model within PHPUnit tests you have to [boot the Lumen](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/testing#creating-and-running-tests) (or Laravel) first by adding the following line to your test class `setUp()` [method](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.0/fixtures.html):

   ```
   parent::setUp()
   ```

Answer (score 9):

Go to `bootstrap/app.php`

then uncomment

```
$app->withEloquent();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just uncomment `$app->withFacades();`, `$app->withEloquent();` lines in `bootstrap/app.php;`

And check again, it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Another less common reason for this error is that you are trying to access an eloquent model before it is ready, e.g in the constructor of a `Job` or perhaps in `app/Console/Kernel.php`

If this is the case, try doing this instead

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$model =  DB::table('table_name')
            ->where('field_name', 'field_value')->first()
```

Comment: this what i faced thanks (y)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried different solutions but seems like problem was very simple.

```
composer du
```

works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Go to bootstrap/app.php

then uncomment

```
$app->withEloquent();
```

worked for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).